# Grails g:resource to asset-pipeline conversion is failing

Tags: css, grails, asset-pipeline

Currently in my Grails app, I have all my CSS/JSS inside `web-app/css` and `web-app/js` respectively, and I refer to them in my GSPs like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<g:resource dir="css" file="myapp.css" />">
<script src="<g:resource dir="js" file="myapp.js" />"></script>
```

I am trying to convert these over to use `asset-pipeline`.

So I added `compile ":asset-pipeline:1.8.11"` to my `BuildConfig#plugins` section, and then moved my CSS/JS files into their appropriate places in `grails-app/assets`. **I leave the `<g:resource>` tags in place.** When the server starts, my app is styled completely wrong, and it is obvious that Grails can't find my CSS/JS files in their new location.

What do I need to do to make this conversion complete & correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the asset pipeline taglibs:

```
 <asset:stylesheet src="myapp.css" />
 <asset:javascript src="myapp.js" />
```

This will look in the grails-app/assets/stylesheets and javascripts to find your resource files.

If you would still rather grab the relative path, you need to use the asset pipeline methods to do so.

The Asset Pipeline can change the path when deployed: 
For example, in the Development environment, none of the resources are minified and combined and the path is something like YOUR_APP/assets/myapp.js .

In the production environment the path would change to just YOUR_APP/assets/SOME_HASH_OF_YOUR_MINIFIED_ASSET

So to get Asset Pipeline to tell you the path use:

```
 ${asset.assetPath(src: 'myapp.js')}
 ${asset.assetPath(src: 'myapp.css')}
```

Letting Asset Pipeline compute the path allows greater flexibility when deploying. For example, if you host an application in the cloud, you could specify a specific CDN (like CloudFront from AWS) to serve your static assets with a simple config change in Config.groovy.